# date.getHours com 0 mais elegante

Tags: javascript, data, time, timepicker

Eu preciso montar um JSON com uma propriedade em horas e minutos. Uso um `Timepicker` no front e ele retorna um date:

```
Fri Feb 15 2019 05:52:09 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão  de Brasília)
```

Para montar o JSON eu faço isso:

```
var horaFormatada = (hora.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + ":" + (hora.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + hora.getMinutes();
```

Que me resulta em:

> 05:52

Isso até funciona, mas me parece meio precário e gostaria de uma solução mais elegante. Alguém tem uma ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart). Como este método só está disponível para strings, primeiro é preciso transformar os valores numéricos em string, e em seguida usar o `padStart`:

```js
let d = new Date();

let horaFormatada = d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
                    d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');

console.log(horaFormatada);
```

Os parâmetros são:

- o tamanho da string final (no caso, 2)
- a string usada para preencher no início (no caso, `'0'`)

Ou seja, se o valor for menor que 10 (como 1, por exemplo), o resultado será `01`. Se o valor for maior que 10, ele não é alterado (como `16`, por exemplo).

---

Se quiser organizar o código, pode colocar isso em uma função:

```js
function formatarValor(valor) {
    return valor.toString().padStart(0, 2);
}

let d = new Date();

let horaFormatada = formatarValor(d.getHours()) + ':' +
                    formatarValor(d.getMinutes());

console.log(horaFormatada);
```

---

Infelizmente a API de datas nativa do JavaScript não fornece muitas opções de formatação, mas existe a opção de usar uma biblioteca externa, como o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```js
// data atual
let d = moment();

let horaFormatada = d.format('HH:mm');
console.log(horaFormatada);

// se você já tiver um Date, também pode criar um moment a partir dele:
let date = new Date();
d = moment(date);
horaFormatada = d.format('HH:mm');
console.log(horaFormatada);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

dá uma olhadinha na documentação do timepicker porque dá pra você informar o formato que você quer que ele te devolva a data. Por exemplo, você disse que ele tá te retornando (Fri Feb 15 2019 05:52:09 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)), é possível passar o formato que você quer que a data retorne, como exemplificado na documentação:

```
 $('#optionExample').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'g:ia' });
```